# Make the list items start at a fixed point in a centred list

Tags: css, html

I want to make the list items in a **centred** list start at a fixed point like this:

[image: List Image]

I tried several solutions from the web but none worked :(

Here is my code:

```css
.body_text {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.13em;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<ul class="body_text">
<li>First Item</li>
<li>Second Item</li>
<li>Thrid Item</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.
Then you can give body_text an offset using a negative left or right margin.

```css
.body_text_wrap {
    text-align: center;
}
.body_text {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.13em;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<div class="body_text_wrap">
<ul class="body_text">
<li>First Item</li>
<li>Second Item</li>
<li>Thrid Item</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a left margin and align it to the center.
You can try doing this,

```
 .body_text {
    margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 5cm;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.13em;
 }
```

Change the left margin according to your needs. This works for me.

Or you can set a relative position, like below,

```
 .body_text {
      position:relative;
      left:50%;
      font-size: 1.13em;
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It works but its a fixed margin... I want something relative so that it will work on all displays :)